# Custom Contact Form on Selected Product Pages

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-form

I need to hide the prices on selected products and on those selected product pages have a button to request a quote which opens a contact form. Upon filling the form the script will send them an email with the price for the product and a link to add the product to the cart.

The reason being certain suppliers do not want prices advertised.

In short what would be the best method to go about having a customised contact form on selected product pages and hiding their prices.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can create an attribute say 'hide price' of type 'yes/no' and assign that attribute to the attribute set. Now for every product for which you want to hide price and show a custom form select 'hide price' attribute value to yes. On the front end i.e on the product's view.phtml file you can check whether the value of 'hide price' attribute is true or false and accordingly you can hide price and show a custom form instead.
Once this happens you can develop a small module to handle the form request and send in an email.